# What is the correct way to type a list of classes inheriting from the same base class?

Tags: typescript, class, types

In TypeScript I'm trying to correctly type a variable of type "Array of Classes inheriting from a base class".

Using this code I get the error '**Cannot create an instance of an abstract class. ts(2511)**' which I understand. But I don't want to instantiate a member of Base, just its descendants.

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract execute(param: string): void;
  protected name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public commonMethod() {
    console.log("Common Method");
  }
}

class A extends Base {
  execute() {
    console.log(`Hello from A, ${this.name}`);
    this.commonMethod();
  }
}

class B extends Base {
  execute() {
    console.log(`Hello from B, no-name`);
  }
}

const list: typeof Base[] = [A, B];

const names = ["Phil", "Andy", "Bob"];

names.map((name) => list.map((cl) => new cl(name)));
```

How would I correctly type `const list: ???[] = [A, B];`

When I switch to `const list: typeof A[] = [A,B]` it works but then suggests all list entries are `A` which they are not.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIKiQzwI4AeOsArhDgBQAOwMAtgFwLkCWAOwDmASl4A3APb8AJgG5iCVlClN4OWQkHBOOXgJGKlsKYPL14UqMx16D0IWIJKSEABb8wAOjt4AvNq6OIokAL6ESqz0IMj8sEhSnJxmALI4HlKyzKIuJCSm5lLION7IUsLMAEQAwkkpggjpmbJVoqEIERGEKGgYAIJU1EyCshjYYHhEJDR0jCy50-mFYMWl5ZUABgASOMjlCABmqpwI-QA0CAAk+B5evsFhm+2uCHc+pslpGe5ZOR1dSK9dBYIYjMZYXB5IZzJg5aEFMyrEplCrMHZ7A7HJJYS6CKQAWj8zwBhG6K0QcUgvAgAE9WDgpIdIZMANoAXQQgVZFyw7OMFKCegw3KqAAVPMgqpcqv1RrTpQgqpgpCAqvzIn4fJxgKxmLZgrl-AA+BBUiDeHV65goI2mwQ4ADuSGQBr0og98iAA)

Comment: Side note: Don't use `map` just to loop through arrays. If you're not using the array it returns (as you aren't in your `names.map(...)` at the end), just use a `for-of` loop, or `forEach`, or [one of the other ways of looping arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: This is really interesting. I can only think of hacks, not *solutions*.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder thanks for the note! Forgot about this when writing the sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a constructor signature instead of the class itself:

```
const list: Array<new (name: string) => Base> = [A, B];

const names = ["Phil", "Andy", "Bob"];

names.map((name) => list.map((cl) => new cl(name)));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gLABQCCokM8COAHjrAK4Q4AUADsDALYBcClAJYA7AOYBKfgDcA9oIAmAbhJl2UGS3g55CYcG45+QscuIqkM4ZUbwZUVnoNHoIiQXNkIAC0FgAdI54ALy6+jimZAC+JObsjCDIgrAW3NyWALI43jLyrOLupGQWVjLIOH7IMqKsAEQAwjKplgiZ2fI14hEI0cQ9JChoGACCNLQswvIY2GB4RIV0DMxs+XNFxWCl5ZXVAAYAEjjIlQgAZurcCEMANAgAJPjevgFhkTudHgiP-rCNacKtXhyeS6PT6xAG6Cwo3GkywuAKZAWTBYeQRRR+JTKFSqrH2h2OZ0aWBuwhkAFpAm8QSQwRjIAhEpB+EMoDAAJ4AHmEOAA7ggHGFnFBXPkggA+OEzCUhADa1ywAF1TP1LPTAhhZTUAAo+ZA1G41IYTNn6hA1TAyEA1JUxYjqvzcYDsVgCgyiiWMiAOp0ulDu3S8pDIV04cRhxRAA)

This will not let you access statics, if you need those you could also use:

```
const list: Array<Omit<typeof Base, never> & (new (name: string) => Base)> = [A, B];

const names = ["Phil", "Andy", "Bob"];

names.map((name) => list.map((cl) => new cl(name)));
list[0].foo();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gLABQCCokM8COAHjrAK4Q4AUADsDALYBcClAJYA7AOYBKfgDcA9oIAmAbhJl2UGS3g55CYcG45+QscuIqkM4ZUbwZUVnoNHoIiQXNkIAC0FgAdI54ALy6+jimZAC+JObsjCDIgrAW3NyWALI43jLyrOLupGQWVjLIOH7IMqKsAEQAwjKplgiZ2fI14hEI0WaFkMAQSQgAZjIyeQXmPT0kKGgYAII0tCzC8hjYYHhEhXQMzGz5O0XFYKXlldUABgASOMiVI+rcCAsANAgAJPjevgFhkSunQ8CF+-lgjTSwlaXhyeS60xixDm6Cwy1W6ywuAKZD2TBYE2ORQhJTKFSqrFu90ew2eWA+whkAFpAkCESQZsjLJAEIlIPwFlAYABPAA8AHluIIIKKIML2DgZMMsVsGTgpDgoAA+BAAMgQDhwAHcDYFnFBXPkgjrNjhxDqQgBtd5YAC6plm3MQgQwTpqAAUfMgah8ags1sKQwgapgZCAau6kT6-NxgOxWA4wladXyICm0xmUNndMakMhMwZxFXTLnHQAGV1+UbjTpAA)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the error is correct. The type of `list` is `typeof Base[]`, and `Base` cannot be instantiated. As far as I know, there's no way to declare `list` to be "an array of non-abstract constructors deriving from `Base`." :-)

So as much as I dislike it, I think your best bet is to let TypeScript believe `Base` isn't abstract and make instantiating it directly a runtime error rather than a compile-time error by disallowing direct construction in the `Base` constructor:

```typescript
class Base {
    // ...

    constructor(name: string) {
        if (new.target === Base) {
            throw new Error("Base cannot be directly instantiated");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here's a complete example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=73#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQA4CcD2ALgsEQCbQB2YAtggFzQQE4CWFA5gNzrQ8bB4KTHAFcSeHAAoqtBsLbsAlCj6YMLAGbRpCAO4A6AmBzsEBaAF4rcRMrRqHmAgAt8uynugBRHPikAieAgkYDAKCkJoACMkUhYcYgIQAE9oNiYwghYwMn9FbkcMAF9VNRcWCH0ZJAtKGgQCzBKMVQQAD2IRIklFBgA3PBZyeybUVSwRKJAWYGgBampBAFkzZzxSHpVCucEIPBAEfRA8dkl-AGE8BcFoFZd1vMbi1BLUUEgYAEFodqIKUhgQSQIww7U63TspUwAiE+0Ox1OAAMABIIEDHaAafDUaCfAA00AAJMhypVqkVEfkoRhSfp5osKHc1hsqWoSq93lA4D82n8ATZgltMGDgF0EJsQQ4YXsDkcTpIUWiMVirnACREALTVSlPaDssbS8zTJgMAjJLAIPBaIEAbQAupZoDb8XA7dw3rtzNUYLUbf4AArOFggfwE-yff7JUPQQJ4KL+N1jAD0SegABUgzBdBIANYQD1CczpIwUYAIH11WiVahgLCSaT1ZQWAB80GNBH0NbrklATdbFE8oAbtEUo+40rhctO4ceqAH7k+ZzAjzUKegAGU8NBSHhy9BSQWZfD5YFZ-O4Gd4-lV6mI+QDxPZQizucz54gWdgCu17Autv4okKRpIWmTZFkHACkgLhuDAYDQKIFBZLQPy+BIQA)):

```typescript
class Base {
    protected name: string;
  
    constructor(name: string) {
        if (new.target === Base) {
            throw new Error("Base cannot be directly instantiated");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
  
    execute(): void {
    }

    public commonMethod() {
        console.log("Common Method");
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    execute() {
        console.log(`Hello from A, ${this.name}`);
        this.commonMethod();
    }
}

class B extends Base {
    execute() {
        console.log(`Hello from B, no-name`);
    }
}

const list: typeof Base[] = [A, B];

const names = ["Phil", "Andy", "Bob"];

// This works
const instances = names.map((name) => list.map((cl) => new cl(name)));
console.log("A");
new A("a");    // So does this
console.log("B");
new B("b");    // And this
console.log("C");
new Base("c"); // But directly instantiating Base throws a runtime error
```